# Maze with path finding algorithm

Tags: java, a-star, maze

I am working on learning how to us a A* algorithm to find paths and I want to see the best way of doing this. This is what I was thinking I want to have a start point and end point then build the maze via a build function then populate it with obstetrical then runt the A* algorithm the print off the route in a table like format basically changing the 0 to a 3 to show the path that is taken (obstetrical will equal a 1). Does this sound like a good plan?

What I am having trouble with is that I don't know the best way to put in the obstetrical in the array. 
This is what I have so far:

```
public class Maze {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {


    //start and end points in the array
    int startx = 115;
    int starty = 655;
    int endx = 380;
    int endy = 560;
    //number of collums and rows
    int row = 700;
    int col = 500;
    //size of maze
    int maze [][] = new int [row][col];

    makeMaze(row, col, maze);
    printMaze(row, col, maze);



}

 //fill mazz with 0
    private static void makeMaze(int row, int col,  int maze[][])
    {   
         //fill maze with 0 for initilization
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                maze[i][j] = 0;
            }

        }
    }
    //print out array/maze
    private static void printMaze(int row, int col,  int maze[][])
    {
         //... Print array in rectangular form
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" " + maze[i][j] );
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
    //fill the array with obsticals
    private void makeObsticals()
    {
        //obstical 1
        //this represent the corners of the object
        int ob1Point1 [][] = new int [220][616];
        int ob1Point2 [][] = new int [220][666];
        int ob1Point3 [][] = new int [251][670];
        int ob1Point4 [][] = new int [272][647];

        //object 2
        int ob2Point1 [][] = new int [341][655];
        int ob2Point2 [][] = new int [359][667];
        int ob2Point3 [][] = new int [374][651];
        int ob2Point4 [][] = new int [366][577];

        //obejct 3
        int ob3Point1 [][] = new int [311][530];
        int ob3Point2 [][] = new int [311][559];
        int ob3Point3 [][] = new int [339][578];
        int ob3Point4 [][] = new int [361][560];
        int ob3Point5 [][] = new int [361][528];
        int ob3Point6 [][] = new int [113][516];

         //object 4
        int ob4Point1 [][] = new int [105][628];
        int ob4Point2 [][] = new int [151][670];
        int ob4Point3 [][] = new int [180][629];
        int ob4Point4 [][] = new int [156][577];
        int ob4Point5 [][] = new int [113][587];

        //object 5
        int ob5Point1 [][] = new int [118][517];
        int ob5Point2 [][] = new int [245][517];
        int ob5Point3 [][] = new int [245][577];
        int ob5Point4 [][] = new int [118][577];

        //object 6
        int ob6Point1 [][] = new int [280][583];
        int ob6Point2 [][] = new int [333][583];
        int ob6Point3 [][] = new int [333][665];
        int ob6Point4 [][] = new int [280][665];

          //object 7
        int ob7Point1 [][] = new int [252][594];
        int ob7Point2 [][] = new int [290][562];
        int ob7Point3 [][] = new int [264][538];

          //object 8
        int ob8Point1 [][] = new int [198][635];
        int ob8Point2 [][] = new int [217][574];
        int ob8Point3 [][] = new int [182][574];


    }
    //astar algorithum
    private void findPath()
    {
    }
```

}

thanks for any help with this

Comment: I don't think you really meant *"obstetrical"*. Obstacles maybe?

Comment: http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/aStarTutorial.htm

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I don't understand why you have declared so many two dimensional array for obstacles...
as you said. . .

```
//obstacle1
//this represent the corners of the object
   int ob1Point1 [][] = new int [220][616];
   int ob1Point2 [][] = new int [220][666];
   int ob1Point3 [][] = new int [251][670];
   int ob1Point4 [][] = new int [272][647];
```

I think from above code you want to mean (220,616),(220,666),(251,670),(272,647) are corner points of 1 obstacle.

If so then I will suggest not to take 4 two dimensional array but instead mark area covered by obstacle in maze[][] array by **infinity** i.e. the highest integer no. (let consider it as a 10000)

and for other (x,y) position,in maze[x][y] put heuristic value of each position (which means cost to reach destination(endx,endy) from that (x,y)position)

and then apply A* algorithm to reach from start to end.

Comment: The reason why I was using a bunch of arrays is that is the best way I could figure out how to "build" the obstacles like I was going to replace all the array values in the area of the obstacles with 1s which represents a non passable way. I am kinda lost by what you mean infinity? So how would I put a heuristic value for each position? I was just marking it as 0 for now I understand that the A* need to know what cost to reach the destination but I am having some trouble figuring that step out.

Comment: @MNM kk.. if m not wrong you basically want in some manner represent obstacles in your maze.  
  
For that, all (x,y) position which are covered by obstacle make maze[x][y] = N (where N is conceptually infinity and as in programming we cannot write infinity so we ll make N a largest possible integer no.)  
Now in your program let the heuristic values ranges from(0 to 1000)then make N = any no. greater than 1000 let N=10000
now in program as 10000 is greater than all possible heuristic value A* algorithm will never consider that position as possible path to reach destination with shortest cost.

Comment: I am a bit lost in building the obstacles in the array. Here is what I was thinking but I does not really work                         for (int i = 220; i < 272; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 616; j < 670; j++)
                {
                    maze[i][j] = 3;
                }
            }

Comment: @MNM yaa u r going in a right path.. but why are you making obstacle's value as 3. does your heuristic ranges from 0 to 2 only?

As I said make it as a large value for an obstacle. and what is your criteria for a heuristic value in your program. I mean how will you decide heuristic value for a (x,y) position?